# Logic App to CosmosDB - PartitionKey extracted from document doesn't match the one specified in the header

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am using a CosmosDB connector in my logic app to insert a record into the database. My container name is ordersContainer. Here is my document:

```json
{
  "id": "98327158-59d3-4b5b-8c36-0b7c6270c18e",
  "item": {
    "headers": {
      "salesNumber": "LXG995",
      "dateTime": "12/23/2020 6:24:40 PM",
      "locationId": "DDD444",
      "locationName": "Wide World Importers",
      "locationAddress": "645 Roosevelt Avenue",
      "locationPostcode": "98121",
      "totalCost": "424.55",
      "totalTax": "42.455"
    },
    "details": [
      {
        "productId": "0f5a0fe8-4506-4332-969e-699a693334a8",
        "quantity": "20",
        "unitCost": "15.99",
        "totalCost": "319.8",
        "totalTax": "31.98",
        "productName": "Beer",
        "productDescription": "Hey this isn't ice cream!"
      },
      {
        "productId": "76065ecd-8a14-426d-a4cd-abbde2acbb10",
        "quantity": "10",
        "unitCost": "4.49",
        "totalCost": "44.9",
        "totalTax": "4.49",
        "productName": "Gone Bananas",
        "productDescription": "I'm not sure how appealing banana ice cream really is."
      },
      {
        "productId": "551a9be9-7f1c-447d-83ee-b18f5a6fb018",
        "quantity": "15",
        "unitCost": "3.99",
        "totalCost": "59.85",
        "totalTax": "5.985",
        "productName": "Matcha Green Tea",
        "productDescription": "Green tea ice cream is good for you because it is green."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In my container, my partition key is /salesNumber and in my connector, I have the 'salesNumber' (with double-quotes around it. However, I get this error:

```
  "code": "BadRequest",
  "message": "Message: {\"Errors\":[\"PartitionKey extracted from document doesn't match the one specified in the header\"]}\r\nActivityId: ba051769-46cc-4890-b199-c65841f3c0da, Request URI: /apps/a13f0c17-4c1e-488f-a4f7-e0fb0c98bb56/services/4b64d4a5-e7e4-4141-a4a1-5a53ab79bc4b/partitions/1108ee0f-f7e4-4572-b6f8-7c63bea5c122/replicas/132551652008533238p/, RequestStats: \r\nRequestStartTime: 2021-01-17T14:21:22.5778297Z, RequestEndTime: 2021-01-17T14:21:22.5778297Z,  Number of regions attempted:1\r\nResponseTime: 2021-01-17T14:21:22.5778297Z, StoreResult: StorePhysicalAddress: rntbd://cdb-ms-prod-eastus1-fd59.documents.azure.com:14308/apps/a13f0c17-4c1e-488f-a4f7-e0fb0c98bb56/services/4b64d4a5-e7e4-4141-a4a1-5a53ab79bc4b/partitions/1108ee0f-f7e4-4572-b6f8-7c63bea5c122/replicas/132551652008533238p/, LSN: 5, GlobalCommittedLsn: 5, PartitionKeyRangeId: 0, IsValid: True, StatusCode: 400, SubStatusCode: 1001, RequestCharge: 1.24, ItemLSN: -1, SessionToken: 5, UsingLocalLSN: False, TransportException: null, ResourceType: Document, OperationType: Upsert\r\n, SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.11.0"
```

I'm not sure why it is saying that the PartitionKey extracted from the document (which should be the above document) doesn't match the one in the header. Well, isn't the header listed in the document?

Any help appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What is the code you are using to insert the new document?  Also, unrelated but why are you using salesOrder as a partition key? Are you expecting to have more than one of them with different id values?

Answer (score 0):

> PartitionKey extracted from document doesn't match the one specified
> in the header

This error causes by your partition key value in your connector isn't the same as the value in your document. In your case, your partition key is `/salesNumber`, so your partition key value in your connector should be `"LXG995"`, not 'salesNumber'(with double-quotes around it).

Answer (score 0):

What the problem was, was that the document I was putting into the container had salesNumber in the item/headers/salesnumber hierarchy. Not being up to speed on how Cosmos does thing, I just thought that it would insert that piece of data into the record as the partition key.

I discovered however that I had to make my partition key 'item/headers/salesNumber' instead of just '/salesNumber'.

I did need to use salesNumber as the partition key to account for the fact that their could be multiple orders from this customer, identified by their salesNumber.

Thanks!